# appcompat_v7 vs \v7\appcompat library project

Tags: android, eclipse

When I once built some simple project, Eclipse automatically generated appcompat_v7 library project in my workspace and include it in dependency list for my original project. Meanwhile, I downloaded new support library (via SDK manager) few times. Then I tried to built again the same project, but this time in dependency section, I manually removed appcompat_v7 and added project generated by successful built of Android-SDK\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat library project. This time I faced few build errors in original project, most of them being unable to find resources that match name "TextAppearance.AppCompat. ..." as parent style of some style tag in res\values\styles.xml (of original project). What am I missing ?

Comment: I don't know if you have any preferences for eclipse, but I would recommend you to start using Android Studio. It is a lot easier to add those dependencies, and it is even smarter than eclipse. You should give it a try.

Comment: Check the api used to compile

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse handles appcompat with many problems. You always must:

- Have a copy of appcompat library loaded into your workspace to import it in your project as library
- Use the same support library version in your project and in the appcompat library. If you update the support library, update it manually in the appcompat and your project. Right button click over appcompat/project, Android Tools -> Add Support Library.
- If you have style compile problems with appcompat library, use compileSdkVersion = 23, targetSdkVersion = 22

Finally, I will recommend to migrate to Android Studio too, much easier and much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Later, I made a **copy** of Android-SDK\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat library project into my workspace (check box when making "new Android project form existing code") and original project compiles well. I considered as better practice not to copy appcompat, but rather to work through reference to it. That way I would have valid link to new version, when I upgrade support library over time. However it appeared as better move to make a copy.